# Ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have two question about the proof of this theorem:

> *Theorem:* Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and $n = \dim_{\mathbb{Q}} K$. Then any ideal $I\neq 0$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

*Proof:* Because $I\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, for any natural number $m\geq 2$ it follows that for every $x \in I$ not $0$ also $mx$ cannot be $0$. So $I$ cannot contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for a $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Now $I$ contains the subgroup $x \mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ for a $0 \neq x \in I$ and is contained in $\mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ itself. So $I\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. $\square$

---

*Questions:*

1.) Why can we conclude that $x \mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$?

2.) Why doesn't it suffice to show that $I$ is contained in a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1) $x \mathcal{O}_K \simeq \mathcal{O}_K$ (and the latter is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$) as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules under the map $z \mapsto x^{-1} z$.

2) Note: I assume you mean to ask "Why **does** it suffice to...".

Since $I$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, it is a free abelian group of rank at most $n$. Then, since $I$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, it also must have rank at least $n$.

Comment: Looks to me as if OP indeed meant what he said in (2), and that the proof he was quoting is extremely sloppy.

Comment: Sadly, I really meant *"Why doesn't it suffice to ..."*. I'm sorry, I don't understand this proof, it's directly from my textbook. Thanks anyway.